# extundelete - failed to read-only open device "/dev/sdb": Error code 2133571347

Tags: mount, data-recovery, recovery-mode

I have a Synology NAS with a RAID 1 setup on which I recently accidentally deleted a shared folder with data I want back. I shut down the NAS and booted into a machine with an Ubuntu Live Cd and attached one of the NAS drives.

I made an image of the drive using DD and now have an oldhd.img file on an external drive.

I then moved to a new machine, booted up with the Live CD attached the external drive and changed to the external drive directory and ran this command

```
mount -r -o loop oldhd.img /mnt
```

Then I ran `fdisk -l` and saw the drive I need to be recovered was `/dev/sdb`

I changed dir to my computer's hard drive folder and ran:

```
extundelete /dev/sdb --restore-all
```

It returns :

```
extundelete - failed to read-only open device "/dev/sdb": Error code 2133571347
```

What am I doing wrong? And what should I do instead?

Comment: Ok so I created an image of the entire disk, not a copy of the file system.
So in this case I read I must specify offset options for losetup? How to do this?

Comment: You ran `extundelete /dev/sdb --restore-all` while I think you need to specify the partition and not the device. It should be `/dev/sdb1` or sdb2 and so on IMO.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mount` with the `-r` option, the filesystem is mounted read only.  In order to do any writing to the disk you must not mount in read only.

So, the command should be

```
mount -o loop oldhd.img /mnt
```

Also, from a sourceforge forum post:

> Error code 2133571347 is  "EXT2_ET_BAD_MAGIC"
>   This means there is no valid signature for the superblock.
>
> Either:
>
> - The superblock is corrupt, in which case you can try to open the file system with help of the superblock copies. see options `-b blocknumber` and `-B blocksize`, or
> - You have made ​​a mistake during the creation of the file system image, or
> - You have created an image of the entire disk, not a copy of the file system, in which case you must specify offset options for losetup.